# Calling Dialog boxes within a class method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class function in a WPF (using .Net 4.0) application that runs through a *synchronous* procedure that needs to make a few stops within it to wait for the user to be ready. So within the procedure I need to pop up some dialogs that just pause the procedure until the user clicks 'ok'.

What's the cleanest way to implement this?

I'm hesitant to muddy the class function with WPF dialogs if there is some way to have the function to signal the MainWindow to call the dialogs instead. Or should I not be worrying about this?

Comment: Is the procedure sync or async? What version of .Net?

Comment: @IAbstract Synchronous. Version 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following until you determine a better way of refactoring. Without knowing any of your specific architecture:

```
void MyLongProcedure() {
    // do some stuff
    if(GetDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { }

    // do some more stuff
    if(GetDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { }
}

DialogResult GetDialog() {
    return myDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

If there is *ever* an option to halt the procedure then you can add a check for `DialogResult.Cancel` and implement a graceful exit to the long procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to give a precise answer with no further details about your app, but I'd go with something like the following (code might not actually compile as is)

```
public class WaitForUserProcedureImpl : IWaitForUserProcedure
{
    public void DoSomething(Action pause)
    {
        // do stuff
        pause(); // pause
        // do more stuff
        // ....
        pause();
    }
}

public class MainWindow: Window
{

    private void button_click(object sender)
    {
        WaitForUserProcedureImpl proc = new WaitForUserProcedureImpl();
        Action myPauseAction = new Action(
            ()=>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Press ok to continue","Press ok to continue",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        );
        proc.DoSomething(myPauseAction);
    }
}
```